# Unable to Upload Video File using Multipart Entity

Tags: android, eclipse, video, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipartentity

I'm trying to upload an video file using Multipart Entity. For using Multipart Entity method, it was mentioned that I should the following jar files httpclient, httpmime, httpcore. But on adding the httpcore jar file I couldn't run my project and it throws the following [error](http://prntscr.com/9c4ihq) in my console.

On removing this particular jar, when I try to run my application my log shows the following [error in my code](http://prntscr.com/9c4jas).

here's my code for your reference:

```
public class UploadActivity extends Activity {
// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private String filePath = null;
private TextView txtPercentage;
private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView vidPreview;
private Button btnUpload;
long totalSize = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

    // Changing action bar background color
    /*
     * getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable( new
     * ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(
     * R.color.action_bar))));
     */

    // Receiving the data from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
    filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

    // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
    boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

    if (filePath != null) {
        // Displaying the image or video on the screen
        previewMedia(isImage);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // uploading the file to server
            new UploadFileToServer().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
 * */
private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
    // Checking whether captured media is image or video
    if (isImage) {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
        // start playing
        vidPreview.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Uploading the file to server
 * */
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("website",
                    new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

/**
 * Method to show alert dialog
 * */
private void showAlert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me solving the issue? Like why I'm getting this error when I try to add Httpcore jar, how can I overcome these...???

Or is there any alternate that I do to make it work????

Comment: Multiple Dex files usually means that it has something to do with your jar file. Check if you are using the same jar twice anywhere in your project ?

Comment: For what it is worth, developing with [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) may cause you problems in the future. It has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is tested and works for uploading video from Android.

It is worth nothing, as Knossos says in the comments to your question, that there are newer, more recommended libraries for HTTP in Android these days, although you may would need to check that they handle Multipart messages properly. A good overview of HTTP in Android (which has an interesting history) is here: https://packetzoom.com/blog/which-android-http-library-to-use.html

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class VideoUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    /* This Class is an AsynchTask to upload a video to a server on a background thread
     * 
     */

    private VideoUploadTaskListener thisTaskListener;
    private String serverURL;
    private String videoPath;

    public VideoUploadTask(VideoUploadTaskListener ourListener) {
        //Constructor
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","constructor");

        //Set the listener
        thisTaskListener = ourListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Upload the video in the background
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","doInBackground");

        //Get the Server URL and the local video path from the parameters
        if (params.length == 2) {
            serverURL = params[0];
            videoPath = params[1];
        } else {
            //One or all of the params are not present - log an error and return
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","One or all of the params are not present");
            return -1;
        }


        //Create a new Multipart HTTP request to upload the video
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);

        //Create a Multipart entity and add the parts to it
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Building the request for file: " + videoPath);
            FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
            StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename:" + videoPath);
            StringBody description = new StringBody("Test Video");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
            reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
            reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","UnsupportedEncodingException error when setting StringBody for title or description");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        //Send the request to the server
        HttpResponse serverResponse = null;
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Sending the Request");
            serverResponse = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ClientProtocolException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Check the response code
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Checking the response code");
        if (serverResponse != null) {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ServerRespone" + serverResponse.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity responseEntity = serverResponse.getEntity( );
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                //log the response code and consume the content
                Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","responseEntity is not null");
                try {
                    responseEntity.consumeContent( );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log the (further...) error...
                    Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOexception consuming content");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        } else {
            //Log that response code was null
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","serverResponse = null");
            return -1;
        }

        //Shut down the connection manager
        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( ); 
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Check the return code and update the listener
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask onPostExecute","updating listener after execution");
        thisTaskListener.onUploadFinished(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;"

in the following line: "FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));"

Comment: Ok - looks like you may be having a problem accessing the jars. See this answer for the way I found best, assuming you are using Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27906193/334402

Comment: S, the problem is the jars, I just tried removing all the jar files and added one by one and it started working fine. Thank for your effort.